# how do I set permissions in a RAID 1data hard drive?

Tags: installation, hard-drive, permissions, raid

I just set up 2 data HD on RAID 1 in Ubuntu 12.04 (soft-raid), they are ext4.
However I can't figure out how to remove permissions on these drives to read and write.
I tried using

sudo chmod ugo+wx /

However it didn't work. 
Also tried:
sudo chmod -R 777 *
However, there are no files, and the permission needs to be set at the drive level, not files and directories.

Finally, I tried downloading 
pysdm

But does not seem to work because drives are set in RAID.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code.

```
mount -ro remount,rw /
```

Replace / with the directory you've mounted your partition to.  It'll remount it with read write privileges.

Comment: Thank you, I tried doing the mount, however the terminal says the HD cannot be found, even if the device is present in the home folder?   I can mount the RAID 1 system, but for some reason I cannot build directories or copy/create files.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Oh I see.  Open the dash and search for "fdisk" and open it.

Fdisk is the Ubuntu default partition manager, and a powerful one at that.  In particular, it will help you set the automount settings for all of your partitions, allowing you to customize the settings to your liking.  You can view all your hard drives on the left side of the screen, and see the partitions and their positions and sizes on the right.

Comment: I could not open fdisk from the dash (could run it from terminal though). But when running disk utilities, it seems that one of the two disks had a few bad sectors, I tried removing the RAID and now both disks seem to have bad sectors. Should I re-format with a new partition scheme?  It is mind boggling since both disks were brand new and in great condition, and I am worried that all this tinkering is damaging the disks.

Comment: Crazy.  Yeah you should do so, but google an application called gparted. This is another partition manager, but focuses more on moving, formatting, creating, and resizing partitions. It's the only partition manager I have ever seen that can move partitions forward and backwards, and safely.  Gparted is really slow when executing changes to the partitions (hours long, best to leave it on overnight or when you're out of the house); but that's because it's significantly more thorough than other applications. I always turn to gparted when "poop gets real" with my hard drives. It's never failed me.

Comment: Gparted works best if you burn the bootable version onto a cd or usb.  It's much safer for your hard drive to run it this way, and it's handy to have a copy on disc available when you need.